# Os.walk to exctract .gz files from all subdirectories using python

Tags: python

I'm using the following code to extract .gz files from all the subdirectories.

I am able to extract the files but the extracted files are not being saved in the subdirectory rather they are getting saved in the main directory/root:

```
   import os, gzip, shutil

   dir_name = r'C:\Users\ngowda\Downloads\DO_driver_logs'
   def gz_extract(directory):
       extension = ".gz"
       os.chdir(directory)
       for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
            for f in files:
               if f.endswith(extension): # check for ".gz" extension
                 gz_name = os.path.join(root, f) # get full path of files
                 print('gz_name',gz_name)
                 file_name = (os.path.basename(gz_name)).rsplit('.',1)[0]
                 print('file_name',file_name)
                 with gzip.open(gz_name,"rb") as f_in, open(file_name,"wb") as f_out:
                 shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
                 os.remove(gz_name) # delete zipped fil
```

I want all the extracted .gz files to be saved in same subdirectory and not in main directory. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing to file described by `file_name` which is

```
file_name = (os.path.basename(gz_name)).rsplit('.',1)[0]
```

`os.path.basename` does *Returns the final component of a pathname* therefore it ends in current working directory. As

```
gz_name = os.path.join(root, f) # get full path of files
```

is already absolute path, it should be sufficient to eliminate `os.path.basename` i.e. replacing

```
file_name = (os.path.basename(gz_name)).rsplit('.',1)[0]
```

using

```
file_name = gz_name.rsplit('.',1)[0]
```

Comment: This worked. I should have been aware that gz_name is already a full path. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is because of `file_name` not having the full path. Change this line:

```
with gzip.open(gz_name,"rb") as f_in, open(file_name,"wb") as f_out:
```

to

```
with gzip.open(gz_name,"rb") as f_in, open(os.path.join(root, file_name),"wb") as f_out:
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Yes passing the ile_name with full path also worked